# Vuetify use v-pagination style on v-data-iterator

Tags: pagination, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I display multiple v-card on my page so I want to set a pagination. I looked for v-pagination but with this component I can't work with my json data (or I didn't understand).

So I see v-data-iterator that I can send json data and I can see the pagination and sort.

But I want to use the v-pagination to replace the default pagination of the v-data-iterator.

It is possible or I have to build all the javascript logic to do my pagination with v-pagination ?